# I don't know how to call a random method from an existing method

Tags: ruby, random, methods

For example, I have a class with 4 methods. In the fourth method I want to call one random method.

For example, this method can call "first", "second" or "third"

```
class Test

  def first
    puts "1"
  end
  def second
    puts "2"
  end
  def third
    puts "3"
  end

  def some

  end
end

test = Test.new
test.some
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Test

  def first
    puts "1"
  end

  def second
    puts "2"
  end

  def third
    puts "3"
  end

  def some
    public_send (self.class.instance_methods(false) - [__method__]).sample
  end
end

test = Test.new
test.some
# >> 1
```

Comment: Nice use of `__method__`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def some
  send public_methods(false).sample
end
```

`some` could call `some` here :)

Comment: Ya but who cares ;)  Even if it does it'll eventually call one of the random methods.

Comment: Also, TIL:  you can send `false` to `public_methods` and `instance_methods` to just get the object's *own* methods.

Comment: @nzifnab I passed `false` as an argument to `public_methods`, didn't I?

Comment: Wow, I've been using hacks like in nzifnab's answer forever. `public_methods(false)` is waaaay nicer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def some
  method_name = (self.public_methods - Object.instance_methods).sample
  public_send(method_name)
end
```

That will probably do it for you :)